# fade out in Image module Python

Tags: python, image, fadeout

I want to take a BMP or JPG and duplicate it so the new image will darker (or brighrt) what function can I use?
Ariel

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ImageEnhance module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageenhance.htm) of PIL:

```
import Image
import ImageEnhance

image = Image.open(r'c:\temp\20090809210.jpg')
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
brighter_image = enhancer.enhance(2)
darker_image = enhancer.enhance(0.5)
```

Look at [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) and ImageEnhance documentation for more details.
Note: I think ImageEnhancer documentation is a bit too terse, and you may need some experimenting within the interactive prompt to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the hard way i.e. code up a pixel by pixel intensity change. Here is how:
1) Convert from [RGB to HSI](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html)
2) Increase or decrease the Intensity component
3) Conver back from HSI to RGB

True fade out i.e. alpha channel is not present in the JPG or BMP formats [ RGBA format image in PIL] . You get black to white using the the intensity technique. If you want to use alpha use png or tiff instead.